# Which one of these is best practice/least computationally expensive?

Tags: vb.net, comparison

```
Private Sub darts_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles darts.Click
    For i = 0 To 20
        MessageBox.Show(i & vbNewLine & i * 2 & vbNewLine & i * 3)
    Next

End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub darts2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles darts2.Click
    For i = 0 To 20
        Dim single_score As Integer = 0
        Dim double_score As Integer = 0
        Dim triple_score As Integer = 0

        single_score = i
        double_score = i * 2
        triple_score = i * 3

        MessageBox.Show(single_score & vbNewLine & double_score & vbNewLine & triple_score)
    Next
End Sub
```

Both achieve the same results obviously.  I wrote the top function, but my friend insists the bottom is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Why don't you run a test to benchmark them?  I'm guessing they both compile to the same or similar IL, so they're probably equivalent.

Comment: Hard to imagine showing a blizzard of 20 MsgBox to the user could ever be considered any sort of Best Practice.  If you are trying to debug the values use `Debug.Print` or `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: You should be able to write your own test to determine which is better.  If you're looking for better ways to make these performance improvements, you might want to ask this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Plutonix -- That's missing the point.  The mbox is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: `Which one of these is best practice`  XY.  Performance is irrelevant if you are showing a modal dialog

Comment: @Plutonix -- The dlg is probably there for debugging.  The OP could remove it and have the same question.

Comment: rory is correct.  the dialog is irrelevant

Comment: The potential trade-off is between readability and performance. To benchmark it you will need to change the MessageBox to a print function of some sort so that user input doesn't affect the timing. There is a StopWatch class in System.Diagnostics for this. The readability of the second example is higher because the added variables explain what the code does - this version will be much easier to come back and fix/modify at a later date.

Comment: The second method does have better readability and even that could be condensed to something like `Dim single_score As Integer = i` rather than setting to 0 etc. I would also turn on **Option Strict**. I also agree with @techturtle to discuss the performance.

Comment: If you remove the dialog, then the first loop won't do anything. This question might be better for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @the_lotus -- Obviously the assumption is to keep the statement being presented in the dialog and just do something else with it that doesn't involve the UI.

Comment: It took 10M iterations to see any noticeable difference, but the former is slightly faster. Of course, I was doing only the math on a dummy variable to eliminate writing to any output, which greatly increases the time needed.

Comment: If the `Messagebox` is irrelevant, supply real code. [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it in a console app. Remove things such as it being in run on the UI thread, and being run inside UI controls' event handlers. Also, the act of displaying the message is *huge* overhead, so leave it out as it's done in each method. All you really want to test is the performance difference between defining variables and assigning calculated values, vs. calculating the values inline with three less variables.

Add a stopwatch to time both methods.

I also added some configuration, so you can decide how many iterations to test, and how many times to average the runs, to smooth out the results.

```
Dim iterations = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).Select(Function(p) CInt(2 ^ p))
Dim averages = 20
Dim durations As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Dictionary(Of Integer, Double))()
For Each iteration In iterations
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)()
    Dim sw As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    For a = 1 To averages
        For i = 0 To iteration - 1
            Dim s = i & vbNewLine & i * 2 & vbNewLine & i * 3
        Next
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    d.Add(1, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / averages)
    sw.Restart()
    For a = 1 To averages
        For i = 0 To iteration - 1
            Dim single_score As Integer = 0
            Dim double_score As Integer = 0
            Dim triple_score As Integer = 0
            single_score = i
            double_score = i * 2
            triple_score = i * 3
            Dim s = single_score & vbNewLine & double_score & vbNewLine & triple_score
        Next
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    d.Add(2, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / averages)
    durations.Add(iteration, d)
Next
For Each iteration In iterations
    Console.WriteLine("Number of iterations: {0}", iteration)
    Console.WriteLine("Method 1: {0:0.0} ms", durations(iteration)(1))
    Console.WriteLine("Method 2: {0:0.0} ms", durations(iteration)(2))
Next
Console.ReadLine()
```

They are pretty much the same

> Number of iterations: 2
>   
> Method 1: 0.0 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.0 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 4
>   
> Method 1: 0.0 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.0 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 8
>   
> Method 1: 0.0 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.0 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 16
>   
> Method 1: 0.0 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.0 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 32
>   
> Method 1: 0.0 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.0 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 64
>   
> Method 1: 0.1 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.1 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 128
>   
> Method 1: 0.1 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.4 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 256
>   
> Method 1: 0.3 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.2 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 512
>   
> Method 1: 0.6 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.4 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 1024
>   
> Method 1: 0.7 ms
>   
> Method 2: 0.7 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 2048
>   
> Method 1: 1.5 ms
>   
> Method 2: 1.1 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 4096
>   
> Method 1: 2.2 ms
>   
> Method 2: 2.2 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 8192
>   
> Method 1: 4.3 ms
>   
> Method 2: 3.5 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 16384
>   
> Method 1: 6.7 ms
>   
> Method 2: 6.7 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 32768
>   
> Method 1: 13.7 ms
>   
> Method 2: 13.4 ms
>   
> Number of iterations: 65536
>   
> Method 1: 28.7 ms
>   
> Method 2: 29.0 ms